# Gallio NAnt Task error: ITestProjectManager service could not be resolved

Tags: .net, nant, gallio

I have the following NAnt targets, inside a larger build file:

```
<target name="load-gallio">
  <loadtasks assembly="lib/Gallio.NAntTasks.dll" />
</target>

<target name="test" depends="load-gallio">
    <gallio failonerror="true">
       <files>
          <include name="target/tests.dll" />
       </files>
   </gallio>
</target>
```

The tests.dll runs fine with the Gallio command line runner, and with Icarus. When I run "nant test", I get the following:

```
load-gallio:

test:

   [gallio] Gallio NAnt Task - Version 3.4 build 12
   [gallio] Start time: 11:12
   [gallio] Stop time: 11:12 (Total execution time: 0.881 seconds)

BUILD FAILED

INTERNAL ERROR

Gallio.Runtime.RuntimeException: Could not resolve component for service type 'Gallio.Runner.Projects.ITestProjectM
anager' because there do not appear to be any components registered and enabled for that service type.
   at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.RegistryServiceLocator.ResolveNonDisabledDescriptor(Type serviceType)
   at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.RegistryServiceLocator.Resolve[TService]()
   at Gallio.Runner.TestLauncher.RunWithRuntime()
   at Gallio.Runner.TestLauncher.Run()
   at Gallio.NAntTasks.GallioTask.RunLauncher(TestLauncher launcher)
   at Gallio.NAntTasks.GallioTask.InternalExecute()
   at Gallio.NAntTasks.GallioTask.ExecuteTask()
   at NAnt.Core.Task.Execute()
   at NAnt.Core.Target.Execute()
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute(String targetName, Boolean forceDependencies)
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute()
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Run()
```

Why does this happen? Am I missing some kind of runtime setup / service registration step? Is this a bug? Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to call the runners directly as it's usually more flexible, and generally removes the dependencies between nant and the utility. I don't know if that's an option for you, but if it is an example may be:

```xml
<exec program="gallio.echo.exe" basedir="Utilities" verbose="true">
    <arg line="target/tests.dll"/>
    <arg value="/rt:XML"/>
    <arg value="/rd:Reports"/>
    <arg value="/no-echo-results"/>
    <arg value="/f:exclude Category:RunManually"/>
</exec>
```

Full documentation for the command line parameters can be found [here](http://www.gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools%3aoptions_for_echo).

Comment: I have already resorted to using exec to invoke echo, and now have that working. So thank you for the suggestion - that is what I have ended up doing. However, if you don't mind, I will not mark your answer as accepted, in the hopes that someone might be able to explain the problem with the NAnt task, which is what the question is actually asking.